# Make two QVBoxLayout resizable within a QHBoxLayout

Tags: qt

I have a QWidget (which works as a window) which has a QHBoxLayout.
This QHBoxLayout contains two QWidget - QWidget1 and QWidget2.

QWidget1 has a QVBoxLayout with two other widgets.
QWidget2 is similar.

When I show the window, the layout looks correctly.
The QWidget1 is on the left, ad QWidget2 is on the right.

If I change the size of the window, the two widgets resize correctly.

The main problem is that I would like to drag the separator between QWidget1 and QWidget2, to resize them. In other words, I would like the two widgets to be MANUALLY resizable.

But their size is fixed within the window.
Can someone suggest me how to move?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`QSplitter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html) which seems to fit your scenario perfectly.